# collations union error

Tags: mysql

while executing my dao class i got this error ...

Message : java.sql.SQLException: Illegal mix of collations for operation 'UNION'
Exception Stack Trace
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Illegal mix of collations for operation 'UNION'

the same program is running on another machine with no error .. what type of problem is that

Answer (score 4):

This means that you are using a UNION clause on two result sets whose collations differ completely or partly.

You need to look at the tables you're querying and identify the collations. Note that individual columns can have a collation that differs from the table's collation.

You may be able to change the collation on the fly for the UNION query alone using the `COLLATE` keyword. The [manual on `COLLATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collate.html) has examples.