# join 2 tables to list results

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables and I need join these tables to show the latest articles from my site

Table **Posts**

```
ID       ID_CAT      ID_USER
10876    5           3489
10877    6           3453
10878    1           2356
10879    4           6789
10880    8           2348
10881    9           8327
```

Table **Posts2**

```
ID       ID_CAT      ID_USER
10882    7           3989
10883    2           3473
10884    7           2246
```

The result should be

```
ID       ID_CAT      ID_USER
10876    5           3489
10877    6           3453
10878    1           2356
10879    4           6789
10880    8           2348
10881    9           8327
10882    7           3989
10883    2           3473
10884    7           2246
```

I have this query from this similar article but not works.
:https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11367/how-to-join-two-table-and-show-one-query-result-in-mysql

```
SELECT name FROM
(
    SELECT name FROM table1
    UNION
    SELECT name FROM table2
) A;
```

Comment: @user1336827 This will simply join the two tables as opposed to `UNION` them, which I think is what the question is asking (see the desired outcome output.)

Comment: yes sorry i thought i deleted that.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't substitute in your own columns for this, try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM Posts UNION SELECT * FROM Posts2) AllPosts;
```

Comment: This is the right approach, personally I would maybe clarify it slightly by giving the table a more obvious alias, such as `AllPosts`, rather than an obscure singel character name.

Comment: @gpmcadam True, I'll edit that in. It does make more sense that way. Thanks!

Comment: I have this error whit these code:  #1271 - Illegal mix of collations for operation 'UNION'

Comment: @josesanchez According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4562386/2581872), that means your two tables have different collations. [Look here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-collate.html) on how to change the collation on the fly.

Comment: Im make the exactly copy from thee first table, but now the error is: Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_63f6_1.MYI'; try to repair it